# How to configure PrimeNG sidebar to leave space for the header and able to push canvas to the right

Tags: angular, primeng

I am building a website using `Angular 7` and `PrimeNG 8`.
The layout of webpage having a fixed header on the top and a side bar navigation menu on the left.

My expected behaviour is when the sidebar toggle, it won't hide the header and also the content will move to the right.

[image]

I have checked the primeng documentation, but no such feature is provided.
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/sidebar

Answer (score 7):

You can simply achieve with css and html, im using plain CSS to expand the side bar when hover on the container for example, you can use JS to handle click event for expanding it :

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
}
nav{
 height:70px;
 background-color: green;
}
.container{
 display: flex;
 height: calc(100vh - 70px);
}
.container .main-body{
 width: 100%;
}
.container aside{
  width: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  background-color: yellow;
}
/*Im using hover event to expand sidebar for example, you can use JS to handle click event*/
.container:hover aside{
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<nav></nav>
<section class="container">
  <aside></aside>
  <div class="main-body">Hover me to display side bar</div>
</section>
```

Here I included [an working example for Angular project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-mnw29c?file=app/app.component.html) .Happy coding !!!

Comment: how would you trigger the JS event with out hover effect

Comment: @RagavanRajan it really depend on the framework you use, ex: Jquery, Angular or React etc... Each have it own declarative way to manipulate css class in the DOM. But the ideal is switching the class, one for expanding, and one for collapsing

Comment: Thanks Ethan. I am using Angular and using ngclass to achieve this but having hard time. Can you pls help

Comment: @RagavanRajan  [here a working stackbliz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-mnw29c?file=app/app.component.html) , happy coding !

Comment: Is this not possible with `p-sidebar`?